Speaker and microphone not working in Ubuntu24.04LTS
I installed the Ubuntu 24.04 on my ThinkPad X1C Gen10, and the speaker and microphone do not work.
The output device is showing "Dummy Output".
restarting the pipewire service, alsa or changing alsa-base.conf (by adding options snd-hda-intel model=auto) do not solve the problem.
Are there any other solutions? Thank you very much!
